# How can I use the current Google App Engine authenticated user to make a http request from GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, oauth-2.0

I work in a big corporation, which has a domain registered in Google. All users authentication is done through Google login page

I have project running in GAE, which is not *(yet)* inside the registered domain (*ie: https://appengine.google.com/a/MYDOMAIN.COM*) and still run on appspot (http://mygreatapp.appspot.com)

To be able to access my App, the users **must** log into our domain.
This is achieved as suggested in the GAE tutorials: *(very simplified version, not actually real code)*

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
currentUser=userService.getCurrentUser();
if (currentUser==null){   //not yet logged-in, so we redirect to the Google login page
    String url=userService.createLoginURL(thisURL);
    HttpResponse.sendRedirect(url);
}else{
    String myOrg=ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAttributes().get("com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService.user_organization");
    if (myOrg!="myOrganization"){
        /* We show an 'unauthorised access page', 
          with a link to the Google logout page */
    {
}
```

Once we get an authenticated user, we also check the `com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService.user_organization` attribute to make sure that the authenticated user is from our domain.

Once correctly authenticated, the user can, at some point, ask the app (GAE) has to issue an *http request* to a service belonging to another App, which **is** in our domain and **requires** to be accessed by an authenticated user (from our domain, of course).
As I already have a perfectly valid user, I would like to use *it* to perform the Http Request.

So, to be clear, my question is:

**How can I use the already authenticated user to call the external service?**

---

**PARTIAL ANSWER**

I think I almost got it!

Here is what I am doing:

The user accesses my app through a jsp page, which behaves basically like a servlet (ie HTTPRequest & HTTPResponse are available).

When access is done with an un-authenticated user, he/she is redirected to the google login page thanks to  `userService.createLoginURL(HttpRequest.getRequestURI());`

Thanks to Google way of managing authentication, once the user has logged-in, he/she is automatically redirected to my jsp page.

When the server receives the request "from" the jsp, I check if the authenticated user belongs to my company (remember the "`com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService.user_organization`" attribute..).
If it's true, I retrieve all the cookies from the HTTPResquest (`HttpRequest.getCookies()`), look for the one named "**ACSID**" and store it.

From there I should be able to use this cookie to make calls on any web-app where the user needs to be authenticated.

But this is where things are going wrong.

- When I simulate locally (on my pc) a GET call with the retrieved cookie to mygreatapp.appspot.com (using NetTool for example), everything goes smoothly.
- When I run my app locally in *Eclipse* (with the cookie hardcoded as you can't actually log in), and make call to mygreatapp.appspot.com, everything also goes smoothly.
- But when I upload the app to Google and I try it, it fails to authenticated (Actually, I get a 302 OK as an answer, and a location header to a login page!). As it's quite hard to debug, I'm a little bit stuck.

Anyone has an idea of what can be failing?

### Thanks a lot!

Finally, I have to admit that there isn't any solution for what I'm trying to achieve. It's actually a good news in a sense, as it proves that Google security isn't that easy to break!
Issue closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you try to use the credentials of a user that is logged in under a Google Apps domain (the ”Domain”) to let an GAE app (”app A”) not running under the Domain access a GAE application (”app B”) running under the Domain and requires all uses to be authenticated under the Domain.

This is bad design and should not work.

I guess that the reason you do not get this to work on the App Engine is that the session cookie is tied to a specific ip-address/range/user-agent

I do not quite understand how you plan to let app A obtain the users’ session cookie since cookies are designed to only be exposed to the originating domain.

The obvious way to do it would be to use oauth.

Comment: Hi Arne, 

Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer.

Your description of my issue is perfectly correct. I agree it sounds a little "dodgy" and it's not the best way to build it. The reason behind it, is that internal approval to get a GAE app inside the company Domain can take forever and I need my users to be able to use the app asap.

I'm going to have a look again at OAuth to see how I can use it.

I also agree that this shouldn't really work.. If it did, it might be a huge gap in Google security, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, your approach would not work because of the cookie issue.

Comment: I had a look to OAuth and also played around a little with the OAuth playground. Actually, I don't really see how it could help me.

As far as I've seen, I'm able to get a Access Token for my app and I could also use it to access Google APIs (Calendar, mail, etc..)

But if I try to use this token to access "App B", I  get redirected to a login page. Probably it is because OAuth is not implemented on their side..

I'll have a deeper look into it and also maybe to OpenID...

Comment: That is correct - Oauth also would need to be implemented on the other side. I cannot think of any way you can accomplish what you try to accomplish without changing App B.

Comment: Last chance would be to change tactics and call the App B webservice from javascript. But it would be a cross-domain request. I'm not really sure how to manage that without being able to change App B.

Comment: Yes in theory that could work, but you would need to change App B to communicate using JASONP ref http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42641/JSON-to-JSONP-Bypass-Same-Origin-Policy

Comment: yeah.. I know.. and I can't modify it.. so it looks like a little bit of an impass there, doesn't it...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this section of the App Engine docs is relevant?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview#Secure_Data_Connection

Comment: Thanks Jonathan,
But I'm afraid not. I think SDC is usefull when you want to access your intranet from GAE. In my case, I just want to access another app, also located in Google, but inside my company domain.

*in any case, and just for the sake of it, I also already tried ;-)*

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Google Accounts 3rd party app authorisation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/).